# Lua - how do I use one lib from another?

Tags: module, lua

I'm having trouble using one Lua lib from inside another. I'm not sure about the best way to do it.

I've got a library that returns a (non-global) table with functions, like this:

```
-- foo.lua
local foo = {}
function foo:m1(...) ... end
function foo:m2(...) ... end
return foo
```

This library can be inserted in either the global or local scope, depending on what the user wants:

```
-- globally
foo = require('foo')
-- or locally
local foo = require('foo')
```

I'm now trying to create another lib (let's call it `bar`) that requires/uses this `foo` lib. Something like this:

```
-- bar.lua
local bar={}
function bar:m3(...)
  ...
  foo:m1()
  ...
end
```

My trouble is - I don't know how to "pass" `foo` to `bar`.

Ideally I'd like to send it as a parameter to `require`:

```
local foo = require('foo')
local bar = require('bar', foo)
```

But I don't think that's possible (is it?). The other option I could think about was adding a `init` method to `bar`:

```
local foo = require('foo')
local bar = require('bar')
bar:init(foo)
```

This works, but doesn't look very clean to me; it's possible to forget adding that third line, leaving `bar` in an "unsafe" state.

Is there a common Lua idiom/method that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `require 'foo'` directly in you `bar` module. This is perfectly legal. The `foo` module will be loaded only once. In order not to leak it out of the `bar` module, store it in a local variable.

You can use this idiom also to separate one big module into several parts, and have one module require all the others. The user will have to `require` only one module.

Comment: But of course! How didn't I think about that! I'll try `require 'foo'` from `bar`, and if that fails, I'll get bar's "path" and try ´require(path .. '.foo')´, else error. Thanks!