# Recommended way to have 2+ modules recursively refer to each other in Lua 5.2

Tags: module, lua, circular-dependency, lua-5.2

Is there a way to have

- Two Lua modules (let's call them `A` and `B`)
- Each module uses functions from the other, so they must `require` each other
- A third module (let's call it `C`) can use `A` but not `B` e.g.

`C.lua`:

```
local A = require 'A'

-- ...

A.foo()
```

- There may be another module `D` that requires `B` but not `A` and/or `E` requiring both `A` and `B`
- Neither `A` nor `B` nor their members should be added to the global namespace.
- Avoid using the `module` and `setfenv` functions (deprecated in Lua 5.2)

---

**Related**: [Lua - how do I use one lib from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939774/lua-how-do-i-use-one-lib-from-another) (note: this solution does not handle circular dependencies.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found quite a simple way to do it:

`A.lua`:

```
local A = {}
local B

function A.foo()
    B = B or require 'B'
    return B.bar()
end

function A.baz()
    return 42
end

return A
```

`B.lua`:

```
local B = {}
local A

function B.bar()
    A = A or require 'A'
    return A.baz()
end

return B
```

Comment: Is there any harm in calling `require` from within a function like this?  I've only ever seen it used at the top level.

Comment: There's no warning in the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) about it, so I think it's safe.

Comment: You can use `require` anywhere in the code. For example, I often use this idiom to start the RemDebug at a given point in file: `if somecondition then require 'remdebug.engine'.start() end`

Answer (score 3):

A standard way to do this in any language is to introduce a mediator.  Modules can then publish and subscribe to the mediator.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

An example of this in my languages is mvccontrib bus, IEventAggregator, and MVVM Lite Messenger class.  They all do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Another method, suggested by Owen Shepherd on [the lua-l mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-12/msg00711.html):

If we set `package.loaded[current-module-name]` at the top of each module, then any other module `require`d later can refer to the current (possibly incomplete) module.

A.lua:

```
local A = {}
package.loaded[...] = A

local B = require 'B'

function A.foo()
    return B.bar()
end

function A.baz()
    return 42
end

return A
```

B.lua:

```
local B = {}
package.loaded[...] = B

local A = require 'A'

function B.bar()
    return A.baz()
end

return B
```

This will not work everywhere.  For example if `B`'s initialization depends on `A.baz` then it will fail if `A` is loaded first, because `B` will see an incomplete version of `A` in which `baz` is not yet defined.

Comment: if you don't want to call require the whole time (in each function as described by [finnw' other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8248862/1162609)), it seems this is the only way left to go. Imho it's quite nice too since the `return modename` at the end of your module is written to `package.loaded[...]` anyway (using this structure of not polluting global namespace and returning tables from modules)