# Lua: How to avoid Circular Requires

Tags: lua, circular-dependency

## Problem

How can I avoid the following error from Lua 5.1 when attempting to do a circular require?

```
$ lua main.lua 
lua: ./bar.lua:1: loop or previous error loading module 'foo'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./bar.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./foo.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    main.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

## File Structure

**main.lua**

```lua
require "foo"
require "bar"
print (Foo.getName())
print (Bar.getName())
```

**foo.lua**

```lua
require 'bar'
Foo = {}
Foo.name = 'foo'

function Foo:getName()
    return Foo.name .. Bar.name
end
```

**bar.lua**

```lua
require 'foo'
Bar = {}
Bar.name = 'bar'

function Bar:getName()
    return Bar.name .. Foo.name
end
```

## Expected Output

```
$ lua main.lua 
foobar
barfoo
```

Comment: Closely related (but for Lua5.2, and avoiding globals): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248698/recommended-way-to-have-2-modules-recursively-refer-to-each-other-in-lua-5-2

Answer (score 14):

## Solution

**main.lua**

```
Foo = Foo or require "foo"
Bar = Bar or require "bar"
print (Foo.getName())
print (Bar.getName())
```

**foo.lua**

```
Foo = {}
Bar = Bar or require "bar"
Foo.name = 'foo'

function Foo:getName()
    return Foo.name .. Bar.name
end

return Foo
```

**bar.lua**

```
Bar = {}
Foo = Foo or require "foo"
Bar.name = 'bar'

function Bar:getName()
    return Bar.name .. Foo.name
end

return Bar
```

## Explanation

Since you are setting global variables, you can check to see if the file has already been required (aka; the global already defined) before attempting another require:

```lua
Bar = Bar or require "bar"
```

Your `bar.lua` would then have to return the definition of Bar;

```lua
Bar = {}
-- ...
return Bar
```

This wont entirely resolve the issue as `bar.lua` is expecting `Foo` to be defined. To resolve this, you can define a dummy variable with the same name:

```lua
Foo = {}
Bar = Bar or require "bar"
```

This is only possible because you are deferring the usage of `Foo` to when the function is called. If you wanted to call `Foo.name` from within the scope of `bar.lua`, you would end up with the same circular dependency issue.

Answer (score 13):

Another way would to solve this issue would be to change the structure of the code and extract the "mutual" functionality into a third module, which both `Foo` and `Bar` would require.

Comment: Ultimately, this is certainly the approach I take which provides a much better dependency tree. In this case, I was curious about a solution which allowed circular dependencies. Thanks!