# how to avoid loops when loading modules in lua

Tags: module, lua, include

I have a situation where I need to use two modules... both of which load / reference another module.  So I'm getting an error about a loop.

Here's the code in module1:

```
require("posix")
posix.setenv("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin")
```

and in module 2 I have the same thing:

```
require("posix")
local ts = posix.stat(spath, "ctime")
```

I found this post: 
[Lua: How to avoid Circular Requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964764/lua-how-to-avoid-circular-requires)

I tried to apply what the above post said and I changed my logic in both modules to look like this:

```
posix = posix or require("posix")
```

But I'm still getting the error message. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

**tester.lua**

```
local main =require("main")
```

**main.lua**

```
module (..., package.seeall)
-- Load libraries
require("commonfunctions")
require("luasql.postgres")
require("session")
```

**commonfunctions.lua**

```
posix = posix or require "posix"
```

**session.lua**

```
posix = posix or require "posix"
```

**Error Message**

```
lua: /usr/share/acf/lib//session.lua:15: loop or previous error loading module 'posix'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/share/lib//session.lua:15: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/share/myapp/main.lua:10: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/share/lua/5.1/posix.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/share/acf/lib//commonfunctions.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./kamfmfm-model.lua:3: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        tester.lua:6: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Comment: Which error message are you getting? What are the modules named?

Comment: lhf, please check out Edit 1 of my post.  Thank you!

Comment: It's not a loop problem like in that SO post you refer to. You don't have A require B and B require A. Does the problem go away if 'main' doesn't require 'session'? Have you tried running each module individually?