# How to avoid circular dependency in lua without global variables?

Tags: lua, require, openresty

I'm using OpenResty and my app is setup as:

```
app/
   clients/
      photoClient.lua
   init.lua
   auth.lua
```

Let's say `photoClient` has both an unauthenticated and a authenticated endpoint (similar to an avatar endpoint that is accessible without logging in, but there may be private photos that you need to login first)

So in terms of dependencies, I have:

```
-- auth.lua

local photoClient = require('app.clients.photoClient')
-- this is used to show avatar on the login page

local auth = {}

auth.isAuthenticated = function ()
   -- logic to check authentication
end

return auth
```

and the client is

```
-- photoClient.lua
local auth = require('app.auth')

local photoClient = {}
photoClient.privateEndpoint = function()
   if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) {
       ngx.exit(403)
   }
   ...
end

photoClient.getAvator = function() {
   -- this is a public method used by auth
}

return photoClient
```

This is giving me a circular dependency issue. I've seen on [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964764/lua-how-to-avoid-circular-requires) that you can use global variables, i.e. to do `photoClient = photoClient or require('app.clients.photoClient')` but I do not want to use global variables and want to keep each module scoped to itself.

How can I do this?

Comment: Inside client module, move the line `local auth = require('app.auth')` inside the body of `privateEndpoint` function

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is that efficient? In almost all other languages you `require` your modules at the beginning, global to the scope of the module itself. If I were to have `anotherPrivateMethod` then I'd have to add `local auth = require('app.auth')` there too. Lua seems different than other languages such as Node, Python in the matter.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to strive moving `require` to the top of the Lua script.

Comment: Slightly confused, you do not want to use global variables as in the example photoClient = photoClient or require ('...') However the act of 'requiring' your module is going to create a global variable called photoClient. It is already there, so what is the harm in testing for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on LuaFlare Documentation by Kate Adams: basically add `package.loaded[...] = your_module` before you do `return your_module` to every file, i.e.

```
-- auth.lua
local auth = {}
package.loaded[...] = auth

local photoClient = require('app.clients.photoClient')

...

return auth


-- photoClient.lua
local photoClient = {}
package.loaded[...] = photoClient

local auth = require('app.auth')

...

return photoClient
```

Fixed the problem. [Here is the link](https://books.google.com/books?id=TOy4BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=lua%20circular%20dependency&source=bl&ots=Btkg5RMUwd&sig=ACfU3U29jqc48aMxzzm2Zed7RXO1T9A3Qg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRsYuhoNvgAhWpwFkKHRDvBzIQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=lua%20circular%20dependency&f=false) to the book's page for anyone who is interested to read more.

Comment: This is not a correct solution.  It looks like an ugly workaround.  The correct solution is to use `require` only where you really need this module.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff can you explain why this is not a correct solution? In terms of "looks" I actually prefer this far over `require` the module inside every method, you call (as a preference).

Comment: Your solution is nothing better then using globals.  Actually, `package.loaded` is a global variable used internally by Lua.  Using implementation-specific details of interpreter to solve pure-logical problem of your code is a workaround, not a solution.  What you really need is a "deferred/lazy require", and there are more clean ways to do this in Lua (compared to using `package.loaded`).  If you have many functions like `provateEndpoint` just write your own `lazy_require()` and place it at the beginning of your script.

Comment: I see, isn't that exactly like Node require work? The `require` also contains a `Module._load` that manages the new modules and caches and is a global variable. But in Node land, when you `export` and `import/require` in another module, the bit of `package.loaded` that I added is self-managed by the engine directly. So I don't really see why it's the correct way in Node, and the wrong way in Lua.

Comment: Why do you want to bring your old Node-land habits to Lua land? Lua is better.  :-)

Comment: BTW, your solution doesn't solve the problem.  You must place `package.loaded[...] = ` at the top of a module, prior to invoking any `require`

Comment: Haha touche! Okay, thanks for your help. Want to write an answer so I can mark as solution?

Comment: Why writing another answer?  Instead I've edited yours.

Answer (score 0):

Two main solutions:

## Split

Split up auth into two modules that handle different aspects: an auth module for common logic that might be used by photoClient and a login module that is the login page.

This solution will prevent the same problem in other cases where you need to use auth.

## Inject

In parent code (init.lua) that owns both of these modules, inject one into the other (call a function that passes the module).